# How can I reduce the app size in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I created a test app. In app there is nothing much. I was using only one button in my main storyboard. After that when I export it app size is 59 MB. I am surprised. I don't understand what has happened. My question is how can I reduce the size?

Comment: did you solve your problem ? please share answer

Comment: No.. i am trying .

Comment: what is your xcode  version ?

Comment: Xcode  Version 8.1 (8B62)

Comment: This problem happened for BitCode .

Comment: my answered! if helped please  accept

Comment: Oky.. But i an unable to do in this time.. stack is allow me to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this problem arises from `BitCode` and you should  disable it in your app. I hope it will be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Swift language is so rapidly evolving, applications need to bundle in the Swift Standard Library, to ensure they have the right version to work with.

You can't do much about that until ABI stability is achieved with Swift 4, which will allow apps to use the Swift Standard Library bundled with the device.

Answer (score -1):

This problem occur due to `BitCode` and may be you are using lot of images with large size. you can reduce least images and also swift is efficient for this .

Comment: i am not used any image in my app